# Books, sites, guides about mental arithmetic by hand and tricks?

Tags: reference-request, arithmetic, book-recommendation, online-resources, mental-arithmetic

Please recommends books I can get, from amazon? I need to get really good at mental math and math by hand, because I'm taking an exam soon  without a calculator.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

One classic text is [The Trachtenberg Speed System](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0313232008), which actually has an amazing history: Trachtenberg created the tools for the book (speed mathematics, including multiplication) while in a Nazi concentration camp, without the use of paper or a writing utensil.

The [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trachtenberg_system) gives a pretty good overview of the book, and [there is a bit about Jakow Trachtenberg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jakow_Trachtenberg) on Wikipedia as well.

p.s. Don't let the \$91 price on Amazon.com worry you; you can find many used copies for less than \$10.

Comment: I got the kindle edition.

Comment: This was magic, can't believe I didn't learn this in school. Thanks.

Comment: @Algific -- glad you liked it.  I didn't know there was a Kindle edition.

Comment: Glad to hear that it's still available. I have a very old copy.

Answer (score 6):

If you're looking for books about rapid arithmetic calculations, then these two books might be what you're looking for. They are [Speed Mathematics](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471467316) and [Short-Cut Math](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0486246116), which will cost you less than $15 for the both of them from Amazon. I bought them for my little sister a few years ago, since she wanted to learn some mental math tricks, and she said that they were both pretty good.

Comment: I also need to do multiplication and division with decimal numbers by hand, is that also in those books?

Comment: I believe they did. They had everything that she had been interested in learning and I'm sure that included decimal multiplication/division.

Answer (score 5):

There is also "Secrets of Mental Math" by Arthur Benjamin.

Answer (score 1):

The best book for mental math and math by hand is Vedic Mathematics by Bharati Krsna Tirthaji. Just search in Google and Amazon.

Answer (score 0):

On the website http://www.math-magic.com/ you can find some [tricks for mental arithmetic](http://www.math-magic.com/pdf.htm).

They are divided into various categories, like [Multiplying numbers](http://www.math-magic.com/multiply_numbers.htm), [Multiplying strategies](http://www.math-magic.com/multiply_srat.htm), [Basic memorization](http://www.math-magic.com/basic_memorization.htm), etc.