# Fast arithmetic, without a calculator?

Tags: arithmetic, mental-arithmetic

This has been on my mind for quite a while now... Is it really crucial to be able to crunch numbers on the fly?

I have considerate difficulty making out the quotient of $1 / 0.732 $ for example. I can approximate it well, but still (~1.3...). When I go for precision, I am too slow.

Are there techniques to accelerate arithmetic operations?

Comment: [Related...](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/54795)

Comment: "Is it really crucial to be able to crunch numbers on the fly?" - well it's sorta kinda embarrassing for me to take long in figuring out how much change I ought to be getting, or reckoning how much to tip the waitress. Otherwise...

Comment: Well, that's not really a problem... But more intensive operations, indeed, drag me down.

Comment: Crucial for what?  It can be useful in some circumstances, but it really depends on your career goals.  A mathematician doesn't really need it, although occasionally mental arithmetic can come in handy in a calculus lecture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doerfler's book [*Dead Reckoning: Calculating Without Instruments*](http://myreckonings.com/Dead_Reckoning/Dead_Reckoning.htm) contains algorithms specifically designed for computing nontrivial things mentally. But it's still not easy and requires quite a lot of practice, I guess. To begin with, one must be really good at multiplying two-digit numbers (so I'm lost there already...).

Answer (score 1):

The first step should be to simplify as much as possible. Start by getting rid of the decimals:
$$
\frac{1}{0.732}=\frac{1000}{732}
$$
Knowing divisibility tests, it's easy to see that the numerator and denominator are divisible by 4, so let's reduce the fraction:
$$
\frac{1000}{732}=\frac{1000\div4}{732\div4}=\frac{250}{(700\div4)+(32\div4)}=\\
\frac{250}{175+8}=\frac{250}{183}
$$
The numerator is larger than the denominator, so we can strip out whole numbers:
$$
\frac{250}{183}=\frac{183}{183}+\frac{67}{183}=1\frac{67}{183}
$$
At that point, you technically have your answer, $1\frac{67}{183}$, but you wanted the decimal places.

For decimals, there's a simple method for denominators which end in 9 that I refer to as [Leapfrog Division](http://headinside.blogspot.com/2013/02/leapfrog-division.html). There's also a [slightly more advanced version for denominators ending in 1](http://headinside.blogspot.com/2014/04/leapfrog-division-ii.html).

I can see that the $183$ will easily scale up to end in a 9 by multiplying by 3, so we'll multiply the numerator and denominator by 3:
$$
1\frac{67}{183}=1\frac{67\times3}{183\times3}=1\frac{201}{549}
$$
Now, we're ready to use the leapfrog division trick to get the decimals. Start by writing down the $1$ followed by decimal point, just to get it out of the way. Next, divide $201$ by $55$ ($55$ is used because $549$ is next to $550$) so as to get a quotient and a remainder:
$$
201\div55=3, \ remainder \ 36
$$
Write down the quotient, $3$, to the right of the decimal point:
$$
1.3
$$
Next, create a new problem by taking the remainder, $36$, and "leapfrog" it in front of the quotient, $3$, to make a new number, $363$. Just as before, you'll divide this number by 55:
$$
363\div55=6, \ remainder \ 33
$$
Write this new quotient to the right of your previous results:
$$
1.36
$$
Again, leapfrog the remainder, $33$, in front of the quotient, $6$, to make a new number, $336$, which you'll divide by $55$. Keep repeating this approach for as many decimals as you deem appropriate, or until you notice they're repeating:
$$
336\div55=6, \ remainder \ 6 \\
Result: \ 1.366 \\
66\div55=1, \ remainder \ 11 \\
Result: \ 1.3661 \\
111\div55=2, \ remainder \ 1 \\
Result: \ 1.36612 \\
12\div55=0, \ remainder \ 12 \\
Result: \ 1.366120 \\
120\div55=2, \ remainder \ 10 \\
Result: \ 1.3661202 \\
102\div55=1, \ remainder \ 47 \\
Result: \ 1.36612021 \\
471\div55=8, \ remainder \ 31 \\
Result: \ 1.366120218 \\
$$
...and so on. I stopped at $1.366120218$, but you shouldn't have any problem understanding how to continue. [According to Wolfram|Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%2F0.732), this calculation is right as far as it goes.

Answer (score 0):

There are methods which apply a few short-cuts for speedy calculations. I would suggest you to go through Trachtenberg's Speed System or Vedic mathematics.